# How to find the base (parent) type of a stereotype in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

Stereotypes are used to extend UMLs type or other stereotypes (that are actually extending UML types). How is it possible in Enterprise Architect to detect the parent of a stereotype especially when the "**_metatype**" attribute is set?

Answer (score 1):

Stereotypes which are defined in the GUI (Settings -- UML Types -- Stereotypes) are stored in the `t_stereotypes` table in the project database. The `AppliesTo` column contains the UML base type. The table can also be accessed via the `Repository.Stereotypes` collection in the API.

Stereotypes from MDG Technologies are not stored in this table. If such stereotypes have been applied, the metatype can be checked in the `Element.MetaType` attribute in the API.

In both cases, `t_object.Object_Type` in the database and `Element.Type` contains the element's base type.